# I need restart server on production if I want to directly change one line of code on the server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, digital-ocean

I have running project ruby on rails on the production server(digital ocean). I only need to add

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

I don't want to push to the repository and update it on the server. I want a direct change on server robot.txt. Question: I need to restart the server? If yes, which command do I need to run for the changes to take effect?

Comment: Are you having vim editor?

Comment: yes i have vim editor

Comment: so you can open file on server like this: sudo vim robot.txt

Comment: @SwapnilPatil all linux servers has the `vi` editor by default.

Comment: I said vim editor. @Зелёный

Comment: You said `vim` but use `vi` in your answer :) Thats not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just edit the `public/robots.txt` it is a static file, no need to reload a server.

Answer (score 0):

You can login with ssh credentials. Go to your file location and open it like this:

```
vi robot.txt
```

insert your changes and restart apache server like this:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```